# How to generate a GraphicsComplex using a quadratic approximation function?

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method

The code below illustrates a finite element mesh composed by quadratic 9-node elemets. I'm using the `GraphicsComplex` and `Polygon` to plot the mesh, and I get a linear interpolation (see the figure). How can I obtain a quadratic interpolation instead?

```
nnodes = {{100.`, 0.`}, {118.9207115002721`, 
    0.`}, {141.42135623730948`, 0.`}, {168.1792830507429`, 
    0.`}, {199.99999999999997`, 0.`}, {92.38795325112868`, 
    38.268343236508976`}, {109.86841134678099`, 
    45.50898605622273`}, {130.65629648763763`, 
    54.11961001461969`}, {155.37739740300373`, 
    64.35942529055826`}, {184.77590650225733`, 
    76.53668647301795`}, {70.71067811865474`, 
    70.71067811865474`}, {84.08964152537145`, 
    84.08964152537145`}, {99.99999999999997`, 
    99.99999999999997`}, {118.92071150027209`, 
    118.92071150027209`}, {141.42135623730948`, 
    141.42135623730948`}, {38.268343236508976`, 
    92.38795325112868`}, {45.50898605622273`, 
    109.86841134678099`}, {54.11961001461969`, 
    130.65629648763763`}, {64.35942529055826`, 
    155.37739740300373`}, {76.53668647301795`, 
    184.77590650225733`}, {0.`, 100.`}, {0.`, 
    118.9207115002721`}, {0.`, 141.42135623730948`}, {0.`, 
    168.1792830507429`}, {0.`, 199.99999999999997`}};
topol = {{1, 3, 13, 11, 2, 8, 12, 6, 7}, {3, 5, 15, 13, 4, 10, 14, 8, 
    9}, {11, 13, 23, 21, 12, 18, 22, 16, 17}, {13, 15, 25, 23, 14, 20,
     24, 18, 19}};
GenerateGraphics[nodes_, topology_] := Block[{meshvis, nodevis},
   meshvis = 
    Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
      GraphicsComplex[nodes, 
       Polygon[topology[[All, {1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8}]]]]}];
   nodevis = 
    Graphics[{MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #1, {-1.8, 1.8}] &, 
       nodes], {PointSize[Large], Black, Point[nodes]}}];
   Show[meshvis, nodevis]
   ];
GenerateGraphics[nnodes, topol]
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to plot only few patches, you can use `ParametricPlot` along with the local parameterizations. This effectively subdivides the patches into smaller polygons and stores them into a `GraphicsComplex`. Notice that at some point,  everything will be transformed into triangles, at least on the GPU.

Comment: "Finite Elements" presentation from the last [WTC](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2017/presentations/#thursday) contains a function `ElementMeshCurvedWireframe` to draw elements with curved edges (on slide 20). It works for 8 noded `QuadElement`, maybe you will need to adjust for your purpose.

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108473/18437) is the corrected link for a post that shows how to visualize a curved `ElementMesh`.

Comment: @andre, thanks. Link is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108457/how-to-draw-the-shape-of-a-2d-2nd-order-element-of-an-elementmesh/108473#108473) provided by @user21, I solved it as follows:

Assembling the line nodes

```
linestopology = Flatten[Table[
    {{topol[[i]][[1]], topol[[i]][[5]], topol[[i]][[2]]},
     {topol[[i]][[2]], topol[[i]][[6]], topol[[i]][[3]]},
     {topol[[i]][[3]], topol[[i]][[7]], topol[[i]][[4]]},
     {topol[[i]][[4]], topol[[i]][[8]], topol[[i]][[1]]}
     }, {i, 1, Length[topol]}], 1];
```

Graphics

```
    GenerateGraphics[nodes_, topology_] := Block[{meshvis, nodevis}, 
  meshvis = Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
     GraphicsComplex[nodes, Polygon[topology[[All, {1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4,8}]]]]}];
  nodevis = Graphics[{MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #1, {-1.8, 1.8}] &, nodes], {PointSize[Large], Black, Point[nodes]}}];
  Show[meshvis, nodevis]]
Clear[interpolatingQuadBezierCurve];
```

Interpolating the smooth lines

```
    interpolatingQuadBezierCurve[pts_List] /; Length[pts] == 3 := 
      BezierCurve[{pts[[1]], 1/2 (-pts[[1]] + 4 pts[[2]] - pts[[3]]),pts[[3]]}];
    interpolatingQuadBezierCurve[ptslist_List] := 
    interpolatingQuadBezierCurve /@ ptslist;
    interpolatingQuadBezierCurveComplex[coords_, indices_] := 
    interpolatingQuadBezierCurve[Map[coords[[#]] &, indices]]
```

Ploting the final mesh

```
Show[GenerateGraphics[nnodes, topol], 
     Graphics[interpolatingQuadBezierCurveComplex[nnodes, linestopology]]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Looks great!

Comment: @user21 Thank you!