# What is quadratic TriangleElement in ToElementMesh?

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

`TriangleElement` support 3 points and 6 points triangles. In the documentation of `TriangleElement`, it explains

> For quadratic triangle elements, the next three incidents are mid-side
> nodes of possibly curved edges

[image]

**What is the formula of the curved edge?**

and I tried a simple example

```
linearTcoordinates = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};
quadraticTcoordinates = {{0, 0}, {0.5, -0.1}, {1, 0}, {0.5, 0.6}, {0, 
    1}, {-0.1, 0.5}};
linearT = 
  ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> linearTcoordinates, 
   "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 3}}]}];
quadraticT = 
  ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> quadraticTcoordinates, 
   "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6}}]}];
```

The two set of coordinates are show below

```
ListPlot[#, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03]] & /@ {linearTcoordinates, 
  quadraticTcoordinates}
```

[image]

Then I inspect the "Wireframe" which I thought for quadratic triangle, I would get a curved triangle. But It is not.

```
{linearT["Wireframe"], quadraticT["Wireframe"]}
```

gives same looking triagnle

[image]

However, the areas are different

```
{linearT["MeshElementMeasure"], quadraticT["MeshElementMeasure"]}
{{{0.5}}, {{0.7}}}
```

**Why is quadratic triagnle the same looking as linear triangle? It should be a curved triangle, right?**

Comment: The 1st paragraph of the [Element Mesh Visualization Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html?view=all) says that "the visualization uses linear elements to visualize the mesh". Currently, you will not be able to visualize higher-order elements with "Wireframe".

Comment: @TimLaska Thank you for comment. Then, is there other way to show the real shape of quadratic triangle?

Comment: It is straightforward to show a crinkly polygon by converting the mesh coordinates and incidents to a graphics complex. For example: `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Orange, 
  GraphicsComplex[quadraticT["Coordinates"], Polygon[First@ElementIncidents[quadraticT["MeshElements"]] /. {{a_, c_, e_, b_, d_, f_} :> {a,b, c, d, e, f}}]] }]`.  To show nice curves, however, would require interpolation and resampling. That would be considerably more difficult, especially for larger meshes.

Comment: Please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108457/18437) answer for visualizing curved elements.

Comment: @user21 Thank you so much. Seems that my post is a duplication.